# Using wildcard in to install a server printer

Tags: java, vbscript, installation, wildcard, wsh

In java, I am trying to use a cmd command to install a printer from a printer server. Knowing the 3 first letters of the printer name, I would like to use wildcards. I have tried the following command but it doesn't do anything.

```
Process p3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "CSCRIPT c:\\windows\\System32\\Printing_Admin_Scripts\\en-US\\prnmngr.vbs -l -s \\\\svmsimp1  -a -p \"slj05%\" " );
```

Comment: What is the printer name you're trying to match?

Answer (score 0):

Read the `prnmngr.vbs` script. There is next function for parsing the command line (abbreviated, omitted parts replaced by `'...'`):

```
' Parse the command line into its components
function ParseCommandLine(iAction, strServer, strPrinter, strDriver _
                                 , strPort, strUser, strPassword)
on error resume next
'...'
dim oArgs
dim iIndex
'...'
iIndex  = 0
set oArgs = wscript.Arguments
while iIndex < oArgs.Count
    select case oArgs(iIndex)
        case "-a"
            iAction = kActionAdd
        '...'
        case "-p"
            iIndex = iIndex + 1
            strPrinter = oArgs(iIndex)
        '...'
        case else
            Usage(true)
            exit function
    end select
    iIndex = iIndex + 1
wend
'...'
end function
```

Crucial line `strPrinter = oArgs(iIndex)` says the script takes printer name from command line parameter `-p "printer"` **as such**, with no attempt to treat any wildcards.  Neither in this function nor anywhere else in the whole script.

BTW, all parameters to the `ParseCommandLine` function are passed by reference (default if `ByVal` and `ByRef` are omitted).

**Conclusion**: although you *would like* to use wildcards, it's impossible with `-a` argument (*add local printer*) as in next call

```
    '...'
    select case iAction
        case kActionAdd
             iRetval = AddPrinter(strServer, strPrinter, strDriver _
                  , strPort, strUser, strPassword)
    '...'
```

we can see (inside `AddPrinter` function):

```
    '...'
    set oPrinter = oService.Get("Win32_Printer").SpawnInstance_
    '...'
oPrinter.DriverName = strDriver
oPrinter.PortName   = strPort
oPrinter.DeviceID   = strPrinter
oPrinter.Put_(kFlagCreateOnly)
    '...'
```

On the other hand, you could parse output from `prnmngr -l -s server` to get desired printer names.

Comment: Thanks got it. I will parse output then. I am wondering if there is way in java to get a list of all printers installations on the printer server. There is one to search for a directory/file (.isdirectory() /.isfile()) but it returns nothing if searching for a printer installation link on the server (\\servername\...).